# Doubt regarding proof from Milnor's notes

Tags: differential-topology

I was reading Milnor's 1958 notes in differential topology and came across the following theorem

> **Theorem**: Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f;U \to \mathbb{R}^p$ be differentiable, where $p \geq 2n$. Given $\epsilon$ >
>   $0$, there is a $p \times n$ matrix $A = (a^i_j)$ with each $|a^i_j| <$
>   $\epsilon$, such that $g(x) = f(x) + Ax$ is an immersion.
>
> **Proof**: $Dg = Df+A$; we would like to choose $A$ in such a way that $Dg(x)$ has rank $n$ for all $x$. i.e. $A$ should be of the form
>   $Q-Df$, where $Q$ has rank $n$.
>
> Define $F_k:\mathcal{M}(p,n;k) \times U \to \mathcal{M}(p,n)$ by the
>   equation $$F_k(Q,x) = Q-Df(x)$$  $\mathcal{M}(p,n;k)$ is a submanifold
>   of $\mathcal{M}(p,n)$ of dimension $k(p+n-k)$. $F_k$ is
>   differentiable, and the domain of $F_k$ has dimension $k(p+n-k)+n$. As
>   long as $k<n$, this expression is monotonic in $k$. Hence the domain
>   of $F_k$ has dimension not greater than
>   $$(n-1)(p+n-(n-1))+n=(2n-p)+pn-1$$ for $k<n$. Since $p\geq 2n$, this
>   dimension is strictly less than $pn=$ dim($\mathcal{M}(p,n)$). Hence
>   the image of $F_k$ has measure zero in $\mathcal{M}(p,n)$, so that
>   there is an element $A$ of $\mathcal{M}(p,n)$, arbitrarily close to
>   the zero matrix, which is not in the image of $F_k$ for $k=0, \dots$ ,
>   $n-1$. Then $A + Df(x)$ has rank $n$ for each $x$.

I dont understand the last part of the proof. i.e. How he concludes that $A+Df$ has rank $n$? Is it because $F_k$ is surjective and hence the chosen $A$ arbitrarily close to the origin satisfies $A=Q-Df(x)$ for some $x$ and $Q$ of rank $n$ and hence $A+Df(x)=Q$ has rank $n$ everywhere ? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: what is $\mathcal{M}(p,n;k)$?

Comment: $p \times n$ matrices of rank $k$. Sorry for not explaining that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A+Df(x)=Q$ has rank $k<n$ for some $x \in U$,  then $A=Q-Df(x)$ so that $A$ is in the image of $F_k$.  This contradicts the fact that $A$ was chosen to be outside the image of $F_k$ for all $k<n$.